# How to make Javascript focus() method work in onBlur event for input text box?

Tags: javascript, dom, xhtml, dom-events

For me Javascript `focus()` method is working fine if I use it with a button and onClick event, but with `onBlur` from a text box, it is not working. Can anyone guide me on this?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function displayResult()
{
var inp1=document.getElementById("text1").value;
var inp2=inp1.length;
if(inp2==0)
{
alert("Field 1 cannot be left Empty");
//document.getElementById("text1").value="";
document.getElementById("text1").focus();
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" name="text1" id="text1" onBlur="displayResult();"/>
<input type="text" name="yext2" id="text2" />


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: add some piece of your code of how you are trying to do it.

Comment: Hello Tasneem, welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide a [short example](http://www.sscce.org) and a snippet of your code [demonstrating](http://www.jsfiddle.net) your problem.

Comment: There's a possibility that even though you successfully request the focus (back, I assume), the onBlur() method is being called before the focus is actually passed on; this means that once your request for focus finishes, the system then goes and completes the onBlur() functionality by giving the focus away... *after* you carefully requested it. A possible work-around is to have onBlur() start a very short timer, say 1000 ms, and in that timer handler set the focus back. This should give the system enough time to complete giving away the focus, but stop the user doing anything elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the time you posted the question, I experimented your issue for an hour using different techniques. It now seems to me that through an event on an input, you cannot set focus on itself.

Still, There is another possible workaround. You can call `displayResult()` when the form is submitted, check if `text1` is empty and cancel submit if it is empty and set focus on `text1`. I have rewritten the code for you.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function displayResult()
{
var inp1=document.getElementById("text1").value;
var inp2=inp1.length;
if(inp2==0)
{
alert("Field 1 cannot be left Empty");
document.getElementById("text1").focus();
return false;
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form onsubmit="return displayResult();">
<input type="text" name="text1" id="text1" />
<input type="text" name="yext2" id="text2" />
<input type="submit"  />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope that helps...

Peace be upon you ...

Answer (score 5):

It's not possible to reapply focus to an element when its *blur* event triggers.  Use a timer with an interval value of `0` to delay the call to focus until afterwards:

```js
function displayResult() {
    var inp1 = document.getElementById("text1").value,
        inp2 = inp1.length;

    if(inp2==0) {
        alert("Field 1 cannot be left Empty");
        //document.getElementById("text1").value="";

        window.setTimeout(function () { 
            document.getElementById("text1").focus();
        }, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: _onblur triggers before the element loses focus_ .. this appears to be untrue. where did you get that info? can you demonstrate it? i tried with this simple [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mrr2kx1s/) and the result was that input already loss focus when blur event is triggered.

Comment: @pumpkinzzz: you're correct, it must have been an incorrect assumption I made ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You need to set little delay in the focusing of the field.

setTimeout(function(){field.focus()}, 10);

like :

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function displayResult(obj)
{
  var inp1=obj.value;
  var inp2=inp1.length;
  if(inp2==0)
  {
    alert("Field 1 cannot be left Empty");
    setTimeout(function(){obj.focus()}, 10);
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="text" name="text1" id="text1" onblur="displayResult(this);"/>
<input type="text" name="yext2" id="text2" />
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I advise you not to use onblur in validating inputs if you are display notification message as alerts. It's quite annoying , it produces endless alerts . 
Validate form onsubmit event.

Comment: Validation on blurring of inputs is much more appropriate, as long as you use unobtrusive methods such as highlighting the incorrect input.  You are right that modal alerts are generally considered obtrusive and frustrating, however.

Comment: Yes I meant to display notification as alerts. Thanks, I have updated my answer.

Comment: `setTimeout()` does not work for me, with 0 or 10 or 100 msec.  :-(

Comment: Try to set focus on element and then return false;

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem in calling focus() on blur event on the same element, if user tries to focus on any other element that does try to refocus itself on blur event (e.g. a button).

But, if there are more than one input elements of type text, password, number, etc., and all of them try to return focus to themselves on blur event, that causes a blur-focus loop between 2 or more elements.

Let us observe a simple example with 2 input elements of type text:

- User fills-in the first input, but it is not valid (e.g. username does not contain at least 6 characters), then moves focus to the second input (presses tab key or clicks on the second input field);
- Blur event triggers on the first input element and calls validation function, which tries to return the focus to the first input element, but that causes...
- Blur event to trigger on the second input element and calls validation function which tries to return focus to the second input element, which further causes blur on the first input element...

This sequence of events may cause different behavior in different browsers, especially if there's also an alert dialog for each invalid input, but the result is obviously an infinite loop of blur and focus events on at least two input elements, even if calling focus() is delayed.

Thus, the easiest solution is to avoid refocusing itself on blur event.