# why onblur="this.focus()" does not work?

Tags: javascript

i would expect that one can not leave such an  input:

Because, wehen leaving, onblur() fires, and calls focus(), which should re-give the focus on the field. 
But it does not work. Did i miss something ?

Comment: Chances are this is a safety measure. Allowing that would lock the user's focus into an element, which is not a good idea.

Comment: May I ask why you are trying to do this?

Comment: Possibly `onblur` is executed before the focus actually leaves the field.  Anyway, please don't lock users into a field, that's Just Wrong.

Comment: because i want to prevent the user to leave a given input field, with an empty value. Whether it is politically incorrect, is another question ;). But i want to understand why it does not work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make javascript focus() method work in onBlur event for input text box?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884399/how-to-make-javascript-focus-method-work-in-onblur-event-for-input-text-box)

Comment: any javascript error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onblur` triggers before the element loses focus. This means that calling focus from within the event is redundant because the element still has it.

also see
[How to make javascript focus() method work in onBlur event for input text box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884399/how-to-make-javascript-focus-method-work-in-onblur-event-for-input-text-box)

Comment: This answer appears to be [from @AndyE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884399/how-to-make-javascript-focus-method-work-in-onblur-event-for-input-text-box#answer-9886348). Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/vQ5Mm/).

Comment: yes this answer is from AndyE. posted for reference within the provided link